# Why is my dialog form data not being passed to my controller in my Ajax Post?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I have created a partial view which takes one parameter on a form "email address", and I would like that string passed to my controller called "InviteTeam" which is decorated as an "HttpPost".

so here is the partial view and the ajax command

```
 <form id="inviteTeam">
<label class="sr-only" for="communityCity">Team Email Address</label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="teamEmailAddress" id="teamEmailAddress" placeholder="Team Email">

    <a href="#" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-sucess">Invite</a>
</form>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {

            var formdata = $("#inviteTeam").serialize();
            alert(formdata);
            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: "/habitats/InviteTeam",

                data: formdata,
                success: function () {
                    $("#inviteModal").modal("hide");
                    window.location.href = "/Habitats/EditCommunity/"
                },
                error: function (errorData) { alert(errorData); }



            })
        });

    });
</script>
```

and here is my controller code: my input string is "email" is null

```
 public ActionResult InviteTeam()
        {
            return PartialView();
        } 

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult InviteTeam(string email)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("EditCommunity", "Habitats");
        }
```

Comment: Because your input has `name="teamEmailAddress"` and that does not match the name of your parameter (`email`). Change one or the other to match. But why in the world are you making an ajax call when you want to redirect.

Comment: thank you ... I will try this

Comment: Just make a normal submit. Your ajax code is degrading performance!

Comment: I thought about that @StephenMuecke thanks I will try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change name="teamEmailAddress" to name="email" Try the following:

```
 <form id="inviteTeam">
    <label class="sr-only" for="communityCity">Team Email Address</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" id="teamEmailAddress" placeholder="Team Email">    
    <a href="#" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-sucess">Invite</a>
</form>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {

            var formdata = $("#inviteTeam").serialize();
            alert(formdata);
            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: "/habitats/InviteTeam",

                data: formdata,
                success: function () {
                    $("#inviteModal").modal("hide");
                    window.location.href = "/Habitats/EditCommunity/"
                },
                error: function (errorData) { alert(errorData); }

            })
        });

    });
</script>
```

Another solution is change the name of the parameter in your action method like:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult InviteTeam(string teamEmailAddress)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("EditCommunity", "Habitats");
    }
```

Also if you only want to redirect then you dont need any ajax call. You can simply redirect in javascript as:

```
 window.location.href = "/Habitats/EditCommunity/"
```

But if you have to do some logic with your email address, then hit that controller action and return JSON as RedirectToAction will not work in AjaxCall like:

```
 return Json("true");
```

In your success method of Ajax, you can check:

```
 success: function (data) {
              if (data == true){
                  $("#inviteModal").modal("hide");
                  window.location.href = "/Habitats/EditCommunity/";
               }
          }
```

Comment: @PaulT.Rykiel - Its my pleasure. Please see my updated answer :)